# Facebook Id will be same or change in future

Tags: facebook

Does facebook changes user's id?

Is there any possibility of change in the id of particular user because I'm using facebook id in my facebook application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If facebook changes your USER ID it would be like gmail changing your email address...
Do not fear - as long as facebook is around your user id will be the same.
Using a users facebook user id as a unique identifier in your database is a great idea.  You should store it as a String, or as a BIGINT(20) value.

Comment: Given the app-scoped user ids featured in Graph API v2, it seems great is only 1 version away from terrible.

Comment: Never say never. FB changed it. Now each app has other ID for an user and it's different from old ID.Old apps have some time to adapt though.

Comment: @zbyszek - reference?

Comment: To be more exact in [Graph 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids) IDs are scoped for an app and different between apps, therefore they are supposed to be different from previous IDs in graph 1.0.

Comment: @zbyszek - but users already authenticated in the past will remain the same even with v2. My answer's intention didn't change...

Comment: Ok, my mistake, you are right, there is a statement:

"_No matter what version they originally used to sign up for your app, the ID will remain the same for people who have already logged into your app. This change is backwards-compatible for anyone who has logged into your app at any point in the past._"

Comment: For users who have not logged into your app, the user ID may change depending on the version of the API that you call. In v1.0 of the API users who have not logged into your app will be referred to by their original Facebook user ID, whereas in v2.0 they will be referred to by an app-scoped ID.


https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: @HiteshRiziya - this is true - but the original question was whether an **existing** FBID would change in the future in the context of saving the ID in an application DB. A user that has not yet logged into your application will not have their ID changed because they do not yet exist in the DB - once a user has logged into your application, their ID will not change.

Comment: I am using Parse and I logged in with 2 FB Accounts one months before.
today I logged in and parse is saving same user again as its Id changed.
so what is solution?

Comment: @MoazSaeed - I'm not really understanding what you are saying. Perhaps it would be better to open a new post and add all the relevant details there - this way, more people will be able to see and help with your issue.

Comment: This is no longer true, in SOME cases, users can get a new Facebook ID: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/212609035764918/ - in my experience it's not every time you delete and re-auth the app, but it's quite possible to get a new app-scoped ID after having an old style ID

Comment: Indeed, facebook generates different user ids.

Comment: Yeah, I got stung by this: Facebook changed my user and now my app no longer fetches the right data! Really sucks, unless I can somehow map my new user ID to the old one.